# Pascal-Нет перегруженной подпрограммы с такими типами параметров

Tags: pascal

[image: изображение]

помогите пожалуйста, выдает ошибку и не даёт решить пример,помогите пожалуйста!!

```pascal
program sistema;
var
  x, D: real;
begin
  write('введите значение x');
  read(x);
  if x<=0 then D:=cos(3*(x*sqr(x)))*sqr(x)+0.2*abs(x) else
    if x>0 then D:=ln(sqrt(0.5*x)+(sqr(sin))*0.1*x); // - ошибка в этой строке где +
  write('ответ',D);
end.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите код текстом (не забудьте про форматирование)

Comment: Синус ***чего***?

Comment: синус 0.5 но синус в квадрате

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неправильная запись второй части формулы. После sin должна идти открывающая скобка и аргумент синуса. Скобки после Sqr обертывают все выражение, которое должно быть в квадрате

```
Sqr(Sin(0.1*x))
```

Comment: спасибо тебе, слушай поможешь еще с одним дельцом пожалуйста

Comment: if x>0 then D:=ln(sqrt(0.5*x))+sqr(sin0.1*x);  -он здесь пишет что ''Встречено '1', а ожидался оператор''

Comment: Скобка куда делась?

Comment: она там не требовалась как я понял, а после синуса её убрал как ты и написал и теперь там полное выражение, мне нужно там написать sin в 2 умноженое на 0,1 умноженое на x , как это сделать*?

Comment: Я ведь уже написал нужный кусок кода

Comment: вижу спасибо большое